# Can I have TortoiseSVN auto-add files?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Is there a way to have TortoiseSVN (or any other tool) auto-add any new .cs files I create within a directory to my working copy so I don't have to remember which files I created at the end of the day?

Comment: It just amazes me how such a fundamental feature is missing from TortoiseSVN, while all kinds of useless bells and whistles are included.

Comment: @MikeNakis: Blorgbeard's second answer has what you're looking for, I think (the "Show unversioned files" checkbox). I am happy with that solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably make a batch file, something like this (untested):

```
dir /b /S *.cs > allcsfiles.txt
svn add --targets allcsfiles.txt
```

I believe svn won't mind you trying to add files which are already versioned..

Anyway, that's probably about as automatic as you will easily get.

Comment: If you are already using TortoiseSVN, you can use TortoiseProc (commando line tool) instead of svn.

http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html

Answer (score 10):

If you just commit your working copy, you'll get a file list showing you your unversioned files, which you can tick to add as you commit. You don't have to add them explicitly before you commit.

Comment: to clarify this: in the commit dialog you must check 'Show unversioned files' (mine was unchecked by default)

Comment: It is fine, when you have 100 files. But useless, when you have 10k of them. :-(

Answer (score 1):

```
svn add --force --auto-props [Path to check in]
```

Worked ok for me.

-Jet

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add a bat file to svn (on the installed server) so that anytime you update a particular branch, that change get mimicked.. I believe its called hooks...

I hope this is what you meant.

Comment: That doesn't solve his problem because, if he hasn't added his new files, the server is oblivious to the existence of those files.

Comment: The hook will be hooked to a folder, not files in it, I suppose?