# How to Auto Add/ Ignore Files of certain Type When They are Created in SVN version Folders

Tags: windows, tortoisesvn

I have a folder under SVN control. And Since I will be creating files on a rapid basis, I want certain file types to be added, and certain file types to be ignored automatically, right after the moment the file is created.

An example would be I want to commit a folder that contains `sln`, `csproj`, and `cs` type of extension to the source control, and whenever I create a new `.cs` file, I want that .cs files to be added to the repository immediately. And I don't want any `.pdb` files to get added to the reopository, so whenever a new `.pdb` is created, *it must be auto-added to the ignore list*.

*Edit: I am looking for a GUI way of doing this, [instead of using command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50737/can-i-have-tortoisesvn-auto-add-files).*

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50737/can-i-have-tortoisesvn-auto-add-files

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to auto-commit files via TortoiseSVN's GUI, so I would opt for a script to do that.

However, they do give you an easy way to ignore file types via the GUI.  If you open up the TortoiseSVN Settings (right click -> TortoiseSVN -> Settings) and look at the General section, you'll see a text box labeled "Global ignore pattern."  It is a space-delimited list of filename patterns.  To add PDB files to the ignore list, append "*.pdb" to the end of the list.